# How to get filename without extension from filepath using regex

Tags: regex, powershell

How do I get the word "ChangeDefaultSharePermissions" out of the below?

```
C:\Temp\build_RegEx_tests\ChangeDefaultSharePermissions.vbs
```

So, it is from the last `\` to `.vbs`.

Comment: Have you at least made an attempt you can share?

Comment: You could use `-match` or `-replace` operator to use regex to modify/extract data from text. Check out https://regex101.com/ to design your regex-pattern to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer finally...thanks "Frode F" for the link...that helped..

```
$text = "C:\Temp\build_RegEx_tests\ChangeDefaultSharePermissions.vbs"

$reg = ($text).split('\')

$newreg = $reg[3].Split('.')

$newreg[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would also work in this case. Your current answer is not a regex solution.

```
PS C:\Users\mcameron> "C:\Temp\build_RegEx_tests\ChangeDefaultSharePermissions.vbs" -replace '.*\\(.+?)\..*', '$1'
ChangeDefaultSharePermissions
```

Some breakdown

1. `.*\\` Match everything up until the last `\`
2. `(.+?)` Capture group that takes everything after that last slash until ...
3. `\..*` which matches a literal period and the rest of the line which should be an extension.
4. Replace that text with the result of the capture group using  `'$1'`

**Sidenote**

The basename property of the file has the same result.

```
 PS C:\Users\mcameron> (Get-Item "C:\Temp\build_RegEx_tests\ChangeDefaultSharePermissions.vbs").basename
 ChangeDefaultSharePermissions
```